# How does `auto` interract with biconditional (iff)

Tags: coq

I noticed, that `auto` is ignoring biconditionals. Here is a simplified example:

```
Parameter A B : Prop.
Parameter A_iff_B : A <-> B.

Theorem foo1: A -> B.
Proof.
  intros H. apply A_iff_B. assumption.
Qed.

Theorem bar1: B -> A.
Proof.
  intros H. apply A_iff_B. assumption.
Qed.

Theorem foo2_failing: A -> B.
Proof.
  intros H. auto using A_iff_B.
Abort.

Theorem bar2_failing: B -> A.
Proof.
  intros H. auto using A_iff_B.
Abort.
```

Now, I know that `A <-> B` is a syntactic sugar for `A -> B /\ B -> A` so I wrote two theorems to extract one or the other:

```
Theorem iff_forward : forall {P Q : Prop},
  (P <-> Q) -> P -> Q.
Proof.
  intros P Q H. apply H.
Qed.

Theorem iff_backward : forall {P Q : Prop},
  (P <-> Q) -> Q -> P.
Proof.
  intros P Q H. apply H.
Qed.

Theorem foo3: A -> B.
Proof.
  intros H.
  auto using (iff_forward A_iff_B).
Qed.

Theorem bar3: B -> A.
Proof.
  intros H.
  auto using (iff_backward A_iff_B).
Qed.
```

1. How come `apply A_iff_B` works and `auto using A_iff_B` does not? I
   thought that `auto n` is performing an exhaustive search of all
   possible sequences of `apply` of length <= n using the hypotheses
   and all theorems in a given database.
2. Is there a standard trick for working with biconditionals or are
   those two projection functions the usual solution?
3. Are such projection functions somewhere in the standard library? I
   could not found them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. How come `apply A_iff_B works` and `auto using A_iff_B` does not?

`auto` generally uses `simple apply` instead of `apply` and this restricted version of `apply` does not handle biconditionals.

> 2. Is there a standard trick for working with biconditionals or are those two projection functions the usual solution?

You can use `Hint Resolve -> (<-)` feature for that:

```
Hint Resolve -> A_iff_B.
Hint Resolve <- A_iff_B. (* if you remove this one, then `auto` won't be able to prove the `bar3` theorem *)

Theorem foo3: A -> B.
Proof. info_auto. Qed. (* look at the output *)
```

> 3. Are such projection functions somewhere in the standard library?

Yes, they are called: `proj1` and `proj2`. Here is how you can find them:

```
Search (?A /\ ?B -> ?A).
```

Or a bit easier to type, but finds a tad more stuff than we need:

```
Search (_ /\ _ -> _).
```