# How to project (with `proj1` or `proj2`) a universally quantified biconditional (iff)?

Tags: coq

How to project (with `proj1` or `proj2`) a universally quantified biconditional (iff) such as in the following example?

```
Parameter T : Set.
Parameter P Q R: T -> Prop.
Parameter H : forall (t : T), P t <-> Q t.
```

When I try to use `proj1 H`, it fails with the following error:

> Error: The term "H" has type "forall t : T, P t <-> Q t" while it is
>   expected to have type "?A /\ ?B".

While I would like to get `forall (t : T), P t -> Q t`.

## Edit

Using the [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47512509/823955), I have now two ways to project the biconditional:

```
Theorem proj1' : (forall t, P t <-> Q t) -> forall t, P t -> Q t.
Proof.
  intros H t.
  exact (proj1 (H t)).
Qed.

Theorem foo : forall (t1 t2 : T),
  (R t1 -> P t1) ->
  (R t2 -> P t2) ->
  R t1 /\ R t2 -> Q t1 /\ Q t2.
Proof.
  intros t1 t2 H1 H2 [H3 H4].

  (* Does not solve the goal, as expected. *)
  auto using H.

  (* Solves the goal, but is unnecessary explicit. *)
  (* auto using (proj1 (H t1)), (proj1 (H t2)). *)

  (* Solves the goal and instanciations are infered. *)
  auto using (proj1' H).
Qed.
```

Now, a function such as `proj1'` seems to be quite useful. If it is not offered in the standard library, is it because such situations are actually not happening often enough to justify it, or is it simply an historical accident?

I do realize that a distinct function would be require for two, three, etc. universal quantification (e.g. `proj1'' : (forall t u, P t u <-> Q t u) -> forall t u, P t u -> Q t u`). But wouldn't functions for up to three or four arguments be enough for most cases?

## Related

[How does `auto` interract with biconditional (iff)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47435258/823955)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a term of type `forall (t : T), P t <-> Q t` is a function, you need to apply it to a `t` of type `T` to get access to the body, which is a pair of proofs:

```
Goal (forall t, P t <-> Q t) -> forall t, P t -> Q t.
Proof.
  intros H t.
  exact (proj1 (H t)).
Qed.
```

The above is like the following (modulo transparency):

```
Definition proj1' : (forall t, P t <-> Q t) -> forall t, P t -> Q t :=
  fun H t => proj1 (H t).
```

## Respond to Edit

One can suggest many proofs of the `foo` theorem. I wouldn't use `proj1'` in any of them:

```
Theorem foo t1 t2 : (R t1 -> P t1) -> (R t2 -> P t2) ->
  P t1 /\ P t2 -> Q t1 /\ Q t2.
```

### Solution 1

`apply` is one smart tactic, it can handle biconditionals:

```
Proof. now split; apply H. Qed.
```

### Solution 2

`intros` can apply lemmas when moving stuff to the context:

```
Proof. now intros _ _ [H3%H H4%H]. Qed.
```

It's like SSReflects's `by move=> _ _ [/H H3 /H H4].`

### Solution 3

Coq can use biconditionals to do rewrites if you `Require Import Setoid.` first:

```
Proof. now rewrite !H. Qed.
```

`!` in front of a term means "rewrite as many times as you can, but at least once".

Comment: It seems to me, that it requires us to unnecessary instantiate some theorems explicitly, while `auto` would be perfectly able to find the correct instantiation by itself. How come a function like `foo` is not defined in the standard library? Is it a _code smell_ to need be in a situation where one needs it?

Comment: I don't think `auto` would be able to solve this goal, but `firstorder` certainly can. The standard library lacks many obvious lemmas. One of the reasons behind that is that the authors tried to keep it simple; another one is that it can be tedious to name such simple lemmas, when the proof is just a simple one-liner. I'm not sure whether this is a code smell in your case, if you provide some more context, then I'll try to take a look.

Comment: I edited the question to try to give an example of what I mean.

Comment: I tried to answer your edit. I never felt the need for a lemma like that, but I'm probably biased.